# $_REQUEST gets parameters but not $_POST when using fetch api

Tags: php, ajax, post, fetch

I am using fetch to send a POST request to the backend 'ajax-admin.php' which then redirects to a php function I have in functions.php. 
I decided to replace xmlHttpRequests with 'fetch' api. 
I do a post request with fetch like this:

```
fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',

        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }


      })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => resolve(data)) // we call resolve with the data
    .catch(err => reject(err));

  });
```

Where the query string of the url has the form:  `action=login&tokend_id=1234`

And on the server side I am using $_POST to retrieve the value of the parameters 'action' and 'token_id'. 
However what I see is that $_POST is empty while $_REQUEST does have the paremeters. So if I do $_POST['token_id'] I get an error because $_POST is empty. But if I do $_REQUEST['token_id'] , I get the value of that parameter.

Any idea why this is happening? 
Why would the parameters be in $_REQUEST but not $_POST.

I checked whether $_POST is empty with this statement:

```
 if ( isset( $_POST ) && 0 === count($_POST) )
```

Thanks

Comment: REQUEST has both post and get, as you see the values in the url, GET is being used not POST

Comment: Because, you're doing a GET request and that won't interact with a POST method (and vice-versa).

Answer (score 2):

> Where the query string of the url...

What you're actually doing here is sending a `POST` request to a URL with a query string.  The query string is parsed and placed into `$_REQUEST` and `$_GET` **regardless of the actual HTTP method used**.  However, `$_POST` can only be populated with an actual `POST` request **with a request body**.

In your `fetch()` call, specify `body: formData`.  `formData` can be represented in this querystring format, or in other ways.  See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body

Comment: So any idea then. why when I use  xmlHttpRequest  POST request , passing the parameters again as part of the query string part of the URL , I actually can retrieve the values with $_POST. This is what is confusing. I would expect fetch and xmlHttpRequest to behave the same way on a POST request but they don't.

Comment: @malena If PHP and your webserver are configured correctly, `$_POST` will never be populated from the querystring itself.  It will only be populated from a parsed POST request body.